# How to make changes to the mongodb using at fix interval of time cron's of nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, triggers

I am trying to make a mongodb trigger which should run daily and perform the task as given specific time to make some changes to every record based on condition.

Comment: may be [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-cron-jobs-in-node-js/) can help you or it would be great if you tell what you've tried so far

Comment: thaks a lot for the help i learnt something new, but in this case i cant do it on node as i have to make trigger in mongo atlas only and from there it will do everyting

Comment: done i have created a whole server to perform the task thanks @VaibhavMandlik

Comment: great! you can add your solution as an answer for future use by others

Comment: wait i will edit the question and then answer it accoringly as the solution have cahnged

Comment: can you tell me how to answer my own question :))

Comment: please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer#:~:text=If%20you%20have%20more%20than,own%20question%20at%20any%20time.)